# How can I show the text of the only "Checked" checkboxes into a Msgbox in Vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I am using vb.net and this is my problem. Suppose I have 3 checkboxes.

- Pizza
- Ice cream
- Fries

What I want to do is when I click the "Pizza" and "Fries", the Msgbox will only show me the text on the "checked" checkboxes:

- Pizza
- Fries

And not include the one checkbox that is unchecked. Any help will be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
MessageBox.Show(String.Join(", ",
                            Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)().
                                     Where(Function(cb) cb.Checked).
                                     Select(Function(cb) cb.Text)))
```

This assumes that all `CheckBoxes` are on the form directly and that they are the only `CheckBoxes` on the form. If they are in some other child container, you would use the `Controls` collection of that container. If there may be other `CheckBoxes` in the same container, you could add a `Panel` and put just these `CheckBoxes` in it. If you prefer your LINQ with query syntax rather than function syntax:

```vb
MessageBox.Show(String.Join(", ",
                            From cb In Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)()
                            Where cb.Checked
                            Select cb.Text))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        AddHandler chkFiries.CheckedChanged, AddressOf checkedChanged
        AddHandler chkIcecream.CheckedChanged, AddressOf checkedChanged
        AddHandler chkPizza.CheckedChanged, AddressOf checkedChanged
    End Sub
    Private Sub checkedChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim checkedNames As String
        For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf ctrl Is CheckBox Then
                Dim chkbox = TryCast(ctrl, CheckBox)
                If chkbox.Checked = True Then
                    checkedNames += chkbox.Text & ","
                End If
            End If
        Next

        MessageBox.Show(checkedNames)
    End Sub
```